# java - iterating a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

if I use a for-each loop on a linked list in java,
is it guaranteed that I will iterate on the elements in the order
in which they appear in the list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Linked list is guaranteed to act in sequential order.

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

> An ordered collection (also known as a
>   sequence). The user of this interface
>   has  precise control over where in the
>   list each element is inserted. The
>   user can  access elements by their
>   integer index (position in the list),
>   and search for  elements in the list.

[iterator()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29)
Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

Answer (score 77):

I found 5 main ways to iterate over a Linked List in Java (including the Java 8 way):

1. *For Loop*
2. *Enhanced For Loop*
3. *While Loop*
4. *Iterator*
5. *Collections’s stream() util (Java8)*

**For loop**

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
System.out.println("==> For Loop Example.");
for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(linkedList.get(i));
}
```

**Enhanced for loop**

```
for (String temp : linkedList) {
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

**While loop**

```
int i = 0;
while (i < linkedList.size()) {
    System.out.println(linkedList.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

**Iterator**

```
Iterator<String> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next()); 
}
```

**collection stream() util (Java 8)**

```
linkedList.forEach((temp) -> {
    System.out.println(temp);
});
```

One thing should be pointed out is that the running time of **For Loop** or **While Loop** is O(n square) because `get(i)` operation takes O(n) time([see this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192581/complexity-of-calling-get-on-a-linkedlist-in-a-for-loop-using-o-notation)). The other 3 ways take linear time and performs better.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about `LinkedList.size()` . +1.

Comment: For iteration just using linkedList.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e)); would also work.

Comment: Linear time and O(n) are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @pooria yes, they are the same.

Comment: Question about the Iterator solution.  Is this creating a new memory structure which copies all the elements of the LinkedList, or does it create a new memory structure that contains references (pointers?) to the value for each element in the LinkedList? Why is this faster than using the get(i) solution? Is it because the get(i) has to traverse the tree, at least partially, linkedList.size() times to get the address for the next element?" (it'd be linkedList.size()*(linkedList.size()+1)/2 times, right?)

Comment: LinkedList.get(index) has O(N) time complexity. Using it in a for or while loop has O(N^2). So the first and third one is O(N^2).

Answer (score 9):

As the definition of Linkedlist says, it is a sequence and you are guaranteed to get the elements in order.

eg:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ForEachDemonstrater {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    LinkedList<Character> pl = new LinkedList<Character>();
    pl.add('j');
    pl.add('a');
    pl.add('v');
    pl.add('a');
    for (char s : pl)
      System.out.print(s+"->");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Linked list does guarantee sequential order.

Don't use *linkedList.get(i)*, especially inside a sequential loop since it defeats the purpose of having a linked list and will be inefficient code.

Use *ListIterator*

```
    ListIterator<Object> iterator = myLinkedList.listIterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each java.util.List implementation is required to preserve the order so either you are using ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector, etc. each of them are ordered collections and each of them preserve the order of insertion (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Adding my inputs for future visitors.*

**First things first: as per $[jls-14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), for-each internally use Iterator.**

Now, when you iterate over LinkedList using a for-each or an iterator then the looping is always sequential.

But this is prone to thread safety issues. So, two things can happen:

1. If you use a non-threadsafe List implementation then you will run into `ConcurrentModificationException`
2. You can use a threadsafe List implementation like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. And if you must use a `LinkedList` only then use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to convert your non-threadsafe LL into a threadsafe LL, but again you need to watch out for using iterator in a threadsafe manner.